# Sending JWT Get Request containing username/password using python

Tags: python, jwt

I have access to an API that I'm trying to start leveraging to automate some tasks and I jumped right into it but was stymied by JWT, which I have never used. I'm also coming off a couple years not using python, so I'm a little rusty. Please bear with me.

Here is a direct quote from the API documentation:

```
The authentication mode for an organization is with a JSON Web Token. Users 
must pass a JSON Web Token (JWT) in the header of each API request made. 

To obtain the JWT, send the user’s API key (UUID) and password in a JSON Web
Token GET Request. The authorization method of “Bearer” and a 
space is then prefixed to the encoded token string returned. The token will 
be tied to the user account that generated the JWT.
```

I've tried with `requests` but I'm get 405 errors, I've also installed and imported `pyjwt` but it's confusing to me. This is essentially what I'm trying to send via python:

```
POST https://<our endpoint>/v1/token/get HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
{
"username": "<myUsername>",
"password": "<myPassword>"
```

I've verified that the target API is working, as there is a small set of functionality that works without JWT and was easily accessed via `requests`

Advice is welcome, as are any tutorials. I've tried to read several JWT tutorials but I'm having a hard time translating it to python.

Thanks!

Comment: 1. Most cases that I know off the token endpoint requires a POST (which you tried) but your description above talks about GET. Can you find out more? 2. A token request with password often looks like this: (in the POST body) "grant_type=password&username=admin&password=123", so maybe you have to replace username with uuid? 3. Once you achieved to get a token you have to add the token like this to the header of every request: "Authorization: Bearer  <token>"  (thats the only only thing that is quite clear here. Pls. edit your question if you have more info or made any progress.

Comment: 4. Get the tool fiddler, that will save some time when you try to figure out the correct format for your reqest, and only when you figured it all out you translate your request to python.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: To obtain the JWT, send the user’s API key (UUID) and password in a JSON Web Token GET Request

Solution using `python_jwt`.

> **Assumptions**:
>     Encoding Method = HS256
>     `claims` Fieldname 'consumerId'
>     `claims` Fieldname 'httpMethod'

Your `JWT` in the `url` looks like:

```
'http://httpbin.org/get?eyJ0eXAiOiAiSldUIiwgImFsZyI6ICJIUzI1NiJ9... (omitted for brevity)
```

`response.json()` contains the requested `JWT` you have to use afterwards.

> **Note**: Your have to use `https://<base url>/v1/token/get`

```
import python_jwt as jwt
# Create claims dictionary for generation of JwToken
claims = {
    'consumerId': 'My App ID',
    'httpMethod': 'GET'
}

import datetime
# create JWToken
jwtoken = jwt.generate_jwt(claims, 'My secret', 'HS256', datetime.timedelta(minutes=5))

response = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/get', jwtoken)
print(response.json())
```

***Tested with Python:3.4.2 - requests:2.11.1***